# Reading XLSX file from Java, discards the very first row which is blank

Tags: row, apache-poi, xlsx

I am reading an ".xlsx" file by the following code. I have found that this discards the very first row in the xls file which is completely blank without any value in any of its cell.
Here is the code>>

```
 file = new FileInputStream(new File(qlfied_fileName));      
 XSSFWorkbook  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);

 XSSFSheet  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(j); 
 Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();   

while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
   XSSFRow row = ((XSSFRow) rowIterator.next());  
   Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); 
   ....
}
```

Can someone please guide me what exactly I have to do so that it will not discard the very first row which is blank ?

Comment: [rowIterator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#rowIterator()) (and iterator) iterates over the **physical** rows as per it's javadoc. If you want to iterate over logical rows you'll have to use getLastRowNum() and getRow().

Comment: you may check this question for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024147/apache-poi-blank-values